# Google maps api suddenly stops displaying map

Tags: google-maps, google-api

The map was working fine yesterday but today it is not displaying.I have tried everything i.e changes the old script and using the api key ,but the map not displayed.This is the code and I am also attaching the javascript code which i am using for the map.

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

// Custom options for map
var options = {
        zoom : 14,
        mapTypeId : 'Styled',
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions : {
            mapTypeIds : [ 'Styled' ]
        }
    };
var styles = [{
    stylers : [ {
        hue : "#cccccc"
    }, {
        saturation : -100
    }]
}, {
    featureType : "road",
    elementType : "geometry",
    stylers : [ {
        lightness : 100
    }, {
        visibility : "simplified"
    }]
}, {
    featureType : "road",
    elementType : "labels",
    stylers : [ {
        visibility : "on"
    }]
}, {
    featureType: "poi",
    stylers: [ {
        visibility: "off"
    }]
}];

var newMarker = null;
var markers = [];

// json for properties markers on map
var props = [{
    title : 'Modern Residence in New York',
    image : '1-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Sale',
    price : '$1,550,000',
    address : '39 Remsen St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA',
    bedrooms : '3',
    bathrooms : '2',
    area : '3430 Sq Ft',
    position : {
        lat : 40.696047,
        lng : -73.997159
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}, 
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}, {
    title : 'Hauntingly Beautiful Estate',
    image : '2-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Rent',
    price : '$1,750,000',
    address : '169 Warren St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA',
    bedrooms : '2',
    bathrooms : '2',
    area : '4430 Sq Ft',
    position : {
        lat : 40.702189,
        lng : -73.995098
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}, {
    title : 'Sophisticated Residence',
    image : '3-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Sale',
    price : '$1,340,000',
    address : '38-62 Water St, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA',
    bedrooms : '2',
    bathrooms : '3',
    area : '2640 Sq Ft',
    position : {
        lat : 40.687417,
        lng : -73.982653
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}, {
    title : 'House With a Lovely Glass-Roofed Pergola',
    image : '4-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Sale',
    price : '$1,930,000',
    address : 'Wunsch Bldg, Brooklyn, NY 11201, USA',
    bedrooms : '3',
    bathrooms : '2',
    area : '2800 Sq Ft',
    position : {
        lat : 40.694120,
        lng : -73.974413
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}, {
    title : 'Luxury Mansion',
    image : '5-1-thmb.png',
    type : 'For Rent',
    price : '$2,350,000',
    address : '95 Butler St, Brooklyn, NY 11231, USA',
    bedrooms : '2',
    bathrooms : '2',
    area : '2750 Sq Ft',
    position : {
        lat : 40.682665,
        lng : -74.000934
    },
    markerIcon : "marker-green.png"
}];

// custom infowindow object
var infobox = new InfoBox({
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 202,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-101, -285),
    zIndex: null,
    boxStyle: {
        background: "url('images/infobox-bg.png') no-repeat",
        opacity: 1,
        width: "202px",
        height: "245px"
    },
    closeBoxMargin: "28px 26px 0px 0px",
    closeBoxURL: "",
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false
});

// function that adds the markers on map
var addMarkers = function(props, map) {
    $.each(props, function(i,prop) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(prop.position.lat,prop.position.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( 
                'images/' + prop.markerIcon,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                new google.maps.Size(36, 36)
            ),
            draggable: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });
        var infoboxContent = '<div class="infoW">' +
                                '<div class="propImg">' +
                                    '<img src="images/prop/' + prop.image + '">' +
                                    '<div class="propBg">' +
                                        '<div class="propPrice">' + prop.price + '</div>' +
                                        '<div class="propType">' + prop.type + '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="paWrapper">' +
                                    '<div class="propTitle">' + prop.title + '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="propAddress">' + prop.address + '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div class="propRating">' +
                                    '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' +
                                    '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' +
                                    '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' +
                                    '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>' +
                                    '<span class="fa fa-star-o"></span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<ul class="propFeat">' +
                                    '<li><span class="fa fa-moon-o"></span> ' + prop.bedrooms + '</li>' +
                                    '<li><span class="icon-drop"></span> ' + prop.bathrooms + '</li>' +
                                    '<li><span class="icon-frame"></span> ' + prop.area + '</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                                '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
                                '<div class="infoButtons">' +
                                    '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-gray btn-o closeInfo">Close</a>' +
                                    '<a href="single.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-green viewInfo">View</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                             '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infobox.setContent(infoboxContent);
                infobox.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        $(document).on('click', '.closeInfo', function() {
            infobox.open(null,null);
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    });
}

var map;
var windowHeight;
var windowWidth;
var contentHeight;
var contentWidth;
var isDevice = true;

// calculations for elements that changes size on window resize
var windowResizeHandler = function() {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    contentHeight = windowHeight - $('#header').height();
    contentWidth = $('#content').width();

    $('#leftSide').height(contentHeight);
    $('.closeLeftSide').height(contentHeight);
    $('#wrapper').height(contentHeight);
    $('#mapView').height(contentHeight);
    $('#content').height(contentHeight);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.commentsFormWrapper').width(contentWidth);
    }, 300);

    if (map) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }

    // Add custom scrollbar for left side navigation
    if(windowWidth > 767) {
        $('.bigNav').slimScroll({
            height : contentHeight - $('.leftUserWraper').height()
        });
    } else {
        $('.bigNav').slimScroll({
            height : contentHeight
        });
    }
    if($('.bigNav').parent('.slimScrollDiv').size() > 0) {
        $('.bigNav').parent().replaceWith($('.bigNav'));
        if(windowWidth > 767) {
            $('.bigNav').slimScroll({
                height : contentHeight - $('.leftUserWraper').height()
            });
        } else {
            $('.bigNav').slimScroll({
                height : contentHeight
            });
        }
    }

    // reposition of prices and area reange sliders tooltip
    var priceSliderRangeLeft = parseInt($('.priceSlider .ui-slider-range').css('left'));
    var priceSliderRangeWidth = $('.priceSlider .ui-slider-range').width();
    var priceSliderLeft = priceSliderRangeLeft + ( priceSliderRangeWidth / 2 ) - ( $('.priceSlider .sliderTooltip').width() / 2 );
    $('.priceSlider .sliderTooltip').css('left', priceSliderLeft);

    var areaSliderRangeLeft = parseInt($('.areaSlider .ui-slider-range').css('left'));
    var areaSliderRangeWidth = $('.areaSlider .ui-slider-range').width();
    var areaSliderLeft = areaSliderRangeLeft + ( areaSliderRangeWidth / 2 ) - ( $('.areaSlider .sliderTooltip').width() / 2 );
    $('.areaSlider .sliderTooltip').css('left', areaSliderLeft);
}

var repositionTooltip = function( e, ui ){
    var div = $(ui.handle).data("bs.tooltip").$tip[0];
    var pos = $.extend({}, $(ui.handle).offset(), { 
                    width: $(ui.handle).get(0).offsetWidth,
                    height: $(ui.handle).get(0).offsetHeight
                });
    var actualWidth = div.offsetWidth;

    var tp = {left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2}
    $(div).offset(tp);

    $(div).find(".tooltip-inner").text( ui.value );
}

windowResizeHandler();
$(window).resize(function() {
    windowResizeHandler();
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('notransition');

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapView'), options);
    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
        name : 'Styled'
    });

    map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(40.6984237,-73.9890044));
    map.setZoom(14);

    if ($('#address').length > 0) {
        newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6984237,-73.9890044),
            map: map,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( 
                'images/marker-new.png',
                null,
                null,
                // new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                null,
                new google.maps.Size(36, 36)
            ),
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, "mouseup", function(event) {
            var latitude = this.position.lat();
            var longitude = this.position.lng();
            $('#latitude').text(this.position.lat());
            $('#longitude').text(this.position.lng());
        });
    }

    addMarkers(props, map);
}, 300);

if(!(('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) {
    $('body').addClass('no-touch');
    isDevice = false;
}

// Header search icon transition
$('.search input').focus(function() {
    $('.searchIcon').addClass('active');
});
$('.search input').blur(function() {
    $('.searchIcon').removeClass('active');
});

// Notifications list items pulsate animation
$('.notifyList a').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).children('.pulse').addClass('pulsate');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).children('.pulse').removeClass('pulsate');
    }
);

// Exapnd left side navigation
var navExpanded = false;
$('.navHandler, .closeLeftSide').click(function() {
    if(!navExpanded) {
        $('.logo').addClass('expanded');
        $('#leftSide').addClass('expanded');
        if(windowWidth < 768) {
            $('.closeLeftSide').show();
        }
        $('.hasSub').addClass('hasSubActive');
        $('.leftNav').addClass('bigNav');
        if(windowWidth > 767) {
            $('.full').addClass('m-full');
        }
        windowResizeHandler();
        navExpanded = true;
    } else {
        $('.logo').removeClass('expanded');
        $('#leftSide').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.closeLeftSide').hide();
        $('.hasSub').removeClass('hasSubActive');
        $('.bigNav').slimScroll({ destroy: true });
        $('.leftNav').removeClass('bigNav');
        $('.leftNav').css('overflow', 'visible');
        $('.full').removeClass('m-full');
        navExpanded = false;
    }
});

// functionality for map manipulation icon on mobile devices
$('.mapHandler').click(function() {
    if ($('#mapView').hasClass('mob-min') || 
        $('#mapView').hasClass('mob-max') || 
        $('#content').hasClass('mob-min') || 
        $('#content').hasClass('mob-max')) {
            $('#mapView').toggleClass('mob-max');
            $('#content').toggleClass('mob-min');
    } else {
        $('#mapView').toggleClass('min');
        $('#content').toggleClass('max');
    }


$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"],
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        var label = ui.item.label;
        var value = ui.item.value;
        var me = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            me.val(value);
        }, 1);
    }
});

$('#tags').tagsInput({
    'height': 'auto',
    'width': '100%',
    'defaultText': 'Add a tag',
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker();

// functionality for autocomplete address field
if ($('#address').length > 0) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address');
    var addressAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);

    google.maps.event.addListener(addressAuto, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = addressAuto.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        }
        newMarker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        newMarker.setVisible(true);
        $('#latitude').text(newMarker.getPosition().lat());
        $('#longitude').text(newMarker.getPosition().lng());

        return false;
    });
}

$('input, textarea').placeholder();

})(jQuery);

<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mapView">
            <div class="mapPlaceholder"><span class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></span> Loading map...</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="filter">
                <h1 class="osLight">Filter your results</h1>
                <a href="#" class="handleFilter"><span class="icon-equalizer"></span></a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <form class="filterForm">
                    <!--<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 formItem">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <!--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="js/price-range.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-touch-punch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/infobox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you reach the maxim number of acces